cannot join to the farm, we have to disconnect the old server first how?
after implementing the new on-premise Sharepoint 2019 with a single Sharepoint server and a single SQL server, the Sharepoint server was damaged. now I am trying to create a new one but while I try to configure it, this error message comes: "cannot join this farm because it contains server sharepoint-1 assigned to the single server farm role. to join an additional server to this farm, first disconnect server sharepoint-1 from the farm and then try again."

The best practice to remove a server from a SharePoint farm is directly from this server, by uninstalling SharePoint and using the PowerShell command Disconnect-SPConfigurationDatabase locally.
Of course, it's not possible if the server is offline. But there is another solution, by using SharePoint Central Administration (if you can access it):
To remove a server from a SharePoint farm by using Central Administration

Verify that the user account that completes this procedure has the following credentials:


The user account that performs this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
The user account that performs this procedure is a member of the Administrators group on the server.


On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the System Settings section, click Manage servers in this farm.

On the Servers in Farm page, locate the row that contains the name of the server that you want to remove, and then click Remove Server.

In the warning that appears, click OK to remove the server or click Cancel to stop the operation. The page updates, and the server that you removed no longer appears in the list of servers.


Source: Remove a server from a farm in SharePoint Servers 2016, 2019, and Subscription Edition

but the server is damaged, how can I remove the old server?? and I already prepared a new server with the same name

So create a new fam instead of extending the faulty-one.

Great, but how can I use the old farm, or I can access the data through the new farm to run the existing sites?
Note that the database is on an external server
